# Is it permissible to use fertilisers?

Tags: halal-haram, fiqh, najis

Can you please tell me if it is  allowed in Islam, to use these type of organic  fertilizers for indoor plants and aquatic plants?

Types of products:

1. Organic humus soil or Organic vermi soil
2. bone meal powder of animal and fish  or blood meal  powder.
3. worm casting organic compost.
4. cow manure soil or compost.

All these items are mostly mixed with natural soil and sand above it".

These products are commonly used in many houses and It is very common thing!

I have heard from one person that it  is not permissible to use these items inside home for aquarium  plants and indoor plants.

Answer (score 0):

It is permissible to use synthetic and inorganic fetilisers. It is also permitted to use organic fertilizers which are considered 'clean' such as compost from vegetation or bone-meal from fish or from a halal animal which is properly slaughtered. There is disagreement on fertilizing using something which is 'unclean' - such as feces, urine or blood.

The Hanafis, Malikis and Shafi'is have stated that collecting and using manure is permissible, although Shafi'is have noted that it is makruh. These three have also stated that if an unclean substance is used to fertilize plants then the produce will remain clean and halal to consume. Some have however put the condition that the substance must not show its taste\smell in the produce. And some have stated that it is obligatory to wash the produce before using it.

The Hanbalis state that if an unclean substance is used to fertilize then the produce is haram to consume, unless it is watered with clean water for a period of time that is enough to remove the fitlh. Some of the Hanbalis also have different views such as for it to be makruh or permissible. Note however that the Hanbalis consider the dung and urine of a halal animal to be clean, so for example cow manure should be considered permissible.

**Ref:** https://islamqa.info/en/answers/231253/

Comment: **Ref:** [Mawsoo’ah al-Fiqhiyyah 25/237](https://shamela.ws/book/11430/15591) and [23/214](https://shamela.ws/book/11430/14167#p1) and [40/107](https://shamela.ws/book/11430/26072).